# What does wrapping Scala lambda expressions in blocks (using both braces and parentheses) before executing them inline achieve?

Tags: scala, lambda

While reading an [article](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/ruby/monads-are-not-metaphors) on monads I noticed that the author wrapped his lambdas in blocks using braces:

```
def foo(bar: String) = {
  ({ () => println(bar) })()
  ({ () => bar.length })()
}
```

**How is that different than just using a single pair of parentheses?** (Which does make sense syntactically.)

I tried both forms in the interpreter and they're both correct:

```
scala> ({ () => println(123) })()
123

scala> ( () => println(123) )()
123
```

My first guess was that it has something to do with scoping rules - but then again, lambdas don't have names so they shouldn't affect the namespace much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does absolutely nothing. The extra set of braces are ignored by the parser.

Compile this code:

```
object Test {
  def x = ({ () => println(123) })()
  def y = ( () => println(123) )()
}
```

with `-Xprint:parser`, and the intermediate result is:

```
[[syntax trees at end of                    parser]]
package <empty> {
  object Test extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def x = (() => println(123))();
    def y = (() => println(123))()
  }
}
```

`x` and `y` result in identical abstract syntax trees.